# Why one variable is accessed globally and other is not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, parameters

I am trying to implement a simple BFS code.

Code:

```
def initalizeVertex():
    n = int(input('Enter the no. of vertices.\n'))
    for vertex in range(n):
        Vertex.append(vertex)
        node_adjacency[vertex] = []

def initalizeUndirectedEdges():
    n = int(input("Enter the no. of edges.\n"))
    print("Enter the space seperated edges.")
    for i in range(n):
        a,b = map(int,input().split())
        node_adjacency[a].append(b)
        node_adjacency[b].append(a)

def bfs():
    current_level = 1
    print(Vertex)
    while(current_level_nodes):
        for current_node in current_level_nodes:
            for child_node in node_adjacency[current_node]:
                if node_parent.get(child_node) == None:
                   node_parent[child_node] = current_node
                   next_level_nodes.append(child_node)
                   node_level[child_node] = current_level
        current_level_nodes = [node for node in next_level_nodes]
        next_level_nodes = []
        current_level += 1
    print(node_level)
    print(node_parent)

def printData():
    print(Vertex)
    print(node_adjacency)
    print(node_parent)
    print(node_level)
    print(current_level_nodes)
    print(next_level_nodes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = 0
    Vertex = []
    node_adjacency = {}
    node_parent = {root:None}
    node_level = {root:0}
    current_level_nodes = [root]
    next_level_nodes = []

    initalizeVertex()
    initalizeUndirectedEdges()

    printData()
    bfs()
```

The codes output is :

[image]

This code gives me the error:

```
in bfs
    while(current_level_nodes):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_level_nodes' referenced before assignment
```

Clearly, the `bfs()` function cannot access the list `current_level_nodes`. I can solve this by passing the list `current_level_nodes` to the `bfs` function.

But, my question is why do I have to pass this list to `bfs()` function when I haven't passed the list `Vertex` to `initalizeVertex()` function and the function could still access and modify it?

Also I haven't passed any parameter to `printData` function but that function prints all the lists and dictionaries without giving any error.

Comment: The sole difference is that `bfs()` contains an assignment to the variable, which makes it a local variable by default.  A reference to a variable in a function that doesn't assign to it is automatically global, as there's nothing else it could possibly be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will try to look for the variable at local scope 1st. If they're not found locally, Python will look for them globally.

for example -

In your printData() function -
Python will try to look for the variables locally, but no variables are defined in this method. So, Python will go at the global scope. It'll pick the values and will print them.

```
def printData():
    print(Vertex)
    print(node_adjacency)
    print(node_parent)
    print(node_level)
    print(current_level_nodes)
    print(next_level_nodes)
```

In another function bfs() -

Python will see current_level_nodes inside a while, and Python will try to find where the variable is defined. Here things will get tricky as you've assigned the same variable in the function later. This will confuse Python, and it'll throw the error.

```
line 1. - while(current_level_nodes):
line 2. - current_level_nodes = [node for node in next_level_nodes]
```

That's why you need to explicitly tell Python that you want to use global variable -

```
global current_level_nodes
```

Comment: I think that's it. @jasonharper comment summarizes this.

Comment: Thanks! It explained everything. I have already upvoted your answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here involves the python compiler having compiled the rest of your function and it realizing that it must bind your variables within the function.  This requires the `global` keyword as previously mentioned.

What is confusing here is that the error is shown on the first usage of the variable and not where the actual problem is.  Here is an example:

access_only.py:

```py
global_list = [1,2,3]

def f():
   for x in global_list:
      print(x)

f()
```

Here, we run it:

```sh
$python access_only.py
1
2
3
```

Now we change the function slightly to include an assignment to the list, as occurs in your code.

access_and_change.py:

```py
global_list = [1,2,3]

def f():
   for x in global_list:
      global_list = [1, 2, 3]
      print(x)

f()
```

Here we run it, but get an error on the `for` line even though the problem actually occurs on the `global_list =`  line:

```sh
$python access_and_change.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "access_and_change.py", line 9, in <module>
    f()
  File "access_and_change.py", line 4, in f
    for x in global_list:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'global_list' referenced before assignment
```

The end result is the same, because you are assigning values to the lists, the `global` keyword must be used.  If you eliminate the assignment within your function, the error goes away completely.

Thinking about this, I noticed that the error message says **local** variable referenced before assignment.  I think the issue here is that because the function contains an assignment, the variable is considered to be local.  Whereas if you just reference a global variable it is not considered a local variable.  So, the assignment causes the variable to be considered **local** and the first time you reference it, python throws this error instead of searching the global/parent namespace because the compiler has already determined that it must be a local variable.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works as expected in one function and not the other.

Comment: I know adding `global` will help access the list but that is not the question. I want to know why the function `printData()` was able to access the list `current_level_node`  and `bfs()` wasn't ? Why I don't have to put `global` in `printData`?

Comment: I think I figured this out, updating this answer.

Comment: The updated answer makes sense and solved my query. Thanks!

Comment: Great, please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define current_level_nodes is global in your bfs function this way :

```
def bfs():
    current_level = 1
    global current_level_nodes
    ...
```

Edit :
To access a global variable inside a function there is no need to use global keyword.
But if we need to assign a new value to a global variable or change it then we can do that by declaring the variable as global.
Because you used

```
next_level_nodes.append(child_node)
```

and

```
current_level_nodes = [node for node in next_level_nodes]
```

You need to use global;
If you didn't modify current_level_nodes in your function there was no need to use global

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works as expected in one function and not the other.

Comment: I know adding global will help access the list but that is not the question. I want to know why the function `printData()` was able to access the list `current_level_node` and `bfs()` wasn't ? Why I don't have to put global in `printData`?

Comment: @Inogueir I Explained more in my new edit