# overwrite variable from parent's function scope

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a recursive function. When i write code like this one. It works fine.

```
def older_func():
    variable = 1
    def func():
       print(variable)

       return func

    return func
older_func()(5)
```

But if I try to reassign my variable after printing i get an error

```
def older_func():
    variable = 1
    def func(n):
       print(variable)
       variable = n
       return func

    return func
older_func()(5)
```

local variable referenced before assignment. on printing step. Please help me understand behavior and way to overcome this.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment

Comment: I executed your code and it did not throw any error..

Comment: Please add the code you're using to call the function, and the full error along with the stack trace.

Comment: @ThePyGuy @ Czaporka done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why one variable is accessed globally and other is not in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061086/why-one-variable-is-accessed-globally-and-other-is-not-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is no error code just returns a function object because you don't call the actual function you Just return it `return func`

but when you call it `return func(n)`
it will raise UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment
so you need to use `nonlocal` Keyword

```py
def older_func():
   variable = 1

   def func(n):
      nonlocal variable
      print(variable)
      variable = n
      return func

   return func(5)
```

Comment: I didn't add calling this two functions. But of course I mean it.  
older_func()(5) - the way i call this code. For now your post doesn't answer my questions in any way